# I have two letters with equal count in a name, how to print both the letters with their count

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to display the letter and it's count if it has maximum count in a name. However, I have two letters (n:2, u:2) with equal count in a name, how to print both the letters with their count as they have maximum and equal count. I could only do for one letter.

```
    name = 'Annuu'
    name = name.lower()
    names = set(name)
    highest = 0
    p = ''

    for i in names:
        if name.count(i) > highest:
             highest = name.count(i)
             p = i
    print(f"{p} {highest}")
```

Comment: Well, store a list rather than only a single element. Can you show what you've tried so far to solve this?

Comment: take a look at `Counter` from `collections`

Comment: Hint: a `Counter` and `OrderedDict` can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Counter object to find the count.
Then find the maximum count to filter the letters.

```
from collections import Counter

name = "annuu"

count_dict = Counter(name)

max_count = max(count_dict.values())

for letter, count in count_dict.items():
    if count == max_count:
        print(letter, count)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Preetham. Really appreciate the help. Also thanks to cricket_007 & Ev.Kounis as I did find these 2 modules so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Store the values in dict and find the max_frequency

```
name = 'Annuu'
name = name.lower()

d={}
for i in name:
    d[i]=d.get(i,0)+1

max_freq = max((d.values()))

for k,v in sorted(d.items(),key=lambda (x,y):(y,x), reverse=True):
    if v == max_freq:
        print(k,v)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: You don't need `list()` here: `max(list(d.values()))`. `max(d.values())` works just fine. `if v < max_freq:` could be replaced with an `else`.

Comment: @Ayxan Great. Edited

Answer (score 0):

This is without using any imports:

```
name = "Onnuu"
name = name.lower()
names = set(name)
print(names)
l = []

for i in names:
    l.append((name.count(i),i))

l.sort(reverse = True)

for i in l:
    if l[0][0] == i[0]:
        print(i[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

An example with `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
name = 'Annuu'
c = Counter(name.lower())
mc = c.most_common()
max_count = mc[0][1]
for i, x in enumerate(mc):
  if x[1] < max_count:
    break
print(mc[:i+1]) # [('n', 2), ('u', 2)]
```

Comment: Not sure why are you slicing it. It may work for particular case but not for all. Try checking your code for input `name='ab'`

Comment: It was to avoid the comparison for the first element. But you are right it fails for such case. I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works and produces the output:
The maximum characters and their respective count is as follows:
n 2
u 2

```
name = 'Annuu'
name = name.lower()
names = set(name)
name_count_dict = {} # Use dictionary because of easy mapping between character and respective max
for current_char in names:
    # First save the counts in a dictionary
    name_count_dict[current_char] = name.count(current_char)

# Use the max function to find the max (only one max at this point but will find the remaining in the lines below)
max_char = max(name_count_dict, key=name_count_dict.get)
max_value = name_count_dict[max_char]

# Find all other characters which match the max-value, i.e. all maximums
array_of_all_maxes = [k for k, v in name_count_dict.items() if v == max(name_count_dict.values())]

print("The maximum characters and their respective count is as follows:")
for max_chars in array_of_all_maxes:
    print(f"{max_chars} {max_value}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a simple solution for the problem without using any external package like **collections**.

> Here,  I written 2 test cases and repeated the same lines of code. You haven't to do like that. What you have more than 2, 3 etc. So it's better to write any other function to test the code by passing different values to it.

```
def get_count_and_highest (name): 
    name = name.lower()
    names = set(name)
    highest = 0
    d = {}

    for ch in names:
        count = name.count(ch)
        if count >= highest:
            highest = count

        if highest in d: 
            d[highest].append(ch) 
        else: 
            d[highest] = [ch]

    return highest, d

#Test case 1
highest, d = get_count_and_highest("Annuu") 
l = d.get(highest,  []) # in case if dictionary d is empty then l will be an empty list
output = {ch: highest for ch in l}

print(highest) # 2
print(d)       # {1: ['a'], 2: ['n', 'u']}
print(l)       # ['n', 'u']
print (output) # {'u': 2, 'n': 2}

# Test case 2
highest, d = get_count_and_highest("Babylon python new one") 
l = d.get(highest,  []) # in case if dictionary d is empty then l will be an empty list
output = {ch: highest for ch in l}

print(highest) # 4
print(d)       # {3: ['o', 'p', 'l', 'b', 't', ' ', 'h', 'y', 'w'], 4: ['n', 'e', 'a']}
print(l)       # ['n', 'e', 'a']
print (output) # {'n': 4, 'e': 4, 'a': 4}
```